# Ambiance - How to close windows at the top?

Tags: window, ambiance

So I've used other OS's in the past and I could always close the Windows by moving the mouse cursor to the far top right corner of the screen and just click with the mouse, but I'm not able to do that with Ambiance.

Is that even possible for Ambiance? I'm using UbuntuMATE.

Cheers! :D

Comment: What about the top left?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. There's only a small ball in the top left and it doesn't close the window, not to mention it can't be clicked by simply moving the mouse all the way up and right.

Comment: Do you mean *screen* or *window*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also on Ubuntu with MATE and Ambiance looks like this:

[image]

There are buttons in top right corner, in all themes there are. Your OS must be missing something... is there a message in theme changing tool when you select Ambiance?

**Update from comments:**
Here's the ultimate solution. Managed to run a quick batch on all those icons with Phatch+ImageMagick, fixed couple manually with GIMP and here it is... Custom Ambiance closeable on very top right corner while maximized:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Jj61b72RMWMVZ3TDdVbmJfbnM/view?usp=sharing

Unpack into `~/.themes/` ... Almost everything is possible on Linux :)

Comment: Actually, I too have all the buttons. To understand what I'm going through, maximize a window now, any window. Now move your mouse cursor all the way to the top right corner, and left-click. On most Desktop Environments you're able to close the window this way (without having to "aim" on the close button), but not on the Ambiance theme.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It doesn't work on my OS this way as well. Those buttons are too small and don't spread to the corner. Same with it's twin Radiance. You tried that theme on GNOME?

Comment: There are couple modified versions of Ambiance on http://gnome-look.org Might be worth a try.

Comment: Let me understand this better, you're talking about Full Screen View not Maximized Screen View. Right? I'm trying to duplicate your issue...

Comment: I understood that it was about normal maximize like by pressing that "square" button (next to "X"). Don't know any program that still has those (this same) buttons in full screen mode...

Comment: @Software_Programineer - Actually no, I'm talking about Maximized windows. If you maximize a window and try to close it by moving your mouse all the way to the top-right and then do a left-click, it's like if you're clicking the title bar, you can even move the window around this way :P

Comment: Guys, these are the steps to reproduce:

* Maximize any window;
* Move your mouse to the top-right corner, as farther as it will go;
* Now left-click with your mouse. 

In most DE's and Themes, you're able to close the Window this way, but not on Ambiance.

Comment: Checked couple different themes and on some it works and on some not... must be theme specific thing. Quick search lead me to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/174526 (it's little off-topic but might be alternative quick solution if you manage to make it work on MATE)

Comment: @TedM. I really appreciate it, but I've had lots of accidental "minimizations" over the past months and so it would be a disaster if I ever set the middle-click to close the windows hehehe. I *really* need to move the mouse all the way, just to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Can you specify a theme that you know this feature does work in? And are you using a Raspberry Pi? (if so which version)
The far top left (not the round X button) closes the window for me. I think muru had the right answer first

Comment: @Amanda: Totally get you, I wouldn't use middle click for that myself :) Here are couple themes that works this way: Adwaita, Albatross, Human, Numix. Actually you don't need to change entire theme, you can just change "Window Border" and leave Ambiance for rest.

Comment: @Software_Programineer For example, the Albatross theme. Or if you use KDE, that works as well. No, I'm not using RaspberryPi :)

Comment: @TedM. Unfortunately I too don't see many options. I'll probably use the Albatross theme as well, I've been using that on Debian an Arch. But I like Ambiance better ;-)

Comment: There you go http://wikisend.com/download/987652/AmbianceCustom.zip ... Unpack it into ~/.themes/. Modified that theme by simply removing padding (border is slimmer but closeable). It's also possible to change sizes of all icons to... 24x24 (without upsampling - GIMP can do that) and retain original border height, but it's a llitle bit more work with all those icons :)

Comment: I've updated my original post with that better solution. Enjoy ;)