# How do I use the scroll wheel click to close apps displayed on Alt+Tab on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher, ux

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

One feature I miss a lot from Windows 10 is being able to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> then use the scroll wheel click to close multiple applications without navigating to them.

The extension [middleclickclose](https://github.com/p91paul/middleclickclose) as suggested by this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/501369/905166) only works for the overlay opened with <kbd>Super</kbd>. Personally, I never use this to navigate or select applications/windows due to the slight lag. The extension does not work with '*Switch applications*' or '*Switch windows*' overlays i.e. the overlay shown with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is this doable?

Comment: @K7AAY, not a duplicate. This question is on closing apps from within the Alt+Tab switcher. Moreover, the question is from 2012!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing an item on the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list with the mouse is not implemented. However, out of the box, you can close apps on the switcher when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.

This might even be faster than the mouse: your one finger is already on <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Just move your other finger from <kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>q</kbd> to close an app without leaving the switcher.

Comment: Good alternative! Quick and easy.

Comment: Do you mean you can close apps without ever letting go of the Alt key? Or do you mean you navigate to the app (i.e. let go of Alt from Alt+Tab), then do Alt+q? Two reasons I don't prefer the latter is because 1) I have to navigate to them and bring the app forward 2) I can't do multiple apps. It's definitely slower having to press Tab multiple times when you close multiple apps especially because I usually have a lot of apps open even with workspaces.

Comment: Did you actually try? If you try, you will experience how it works. If you consider my answer correct, even if it does not fully satisfy your wishes, please accept it.

Comment: It wasn't working but I realized it's because I changed the alt+tab shortcut to switch between windows (just like on Win10), instead of applications. Useful feature to know regardless.

Comment: Indeed, this works only on the default Alt+tab application switcher.